# Webpack: Duplicate imports on sass-loader, css-loader(modules: true)

Tags: webpack, css-modules, sass-loader

This [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/145) is not yet resolved and I need help here. HELP!

My Question is: **How do you setup webpack sass-loader with css-loader, setup to do css modules, to prevent duplicate imports**?

Can anyone point me out how can I start resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin

This is what finally ended up working for me.  I swapped out the cssnano step from post-css, and let optimize-css-assets handle it for me.

Im guessing your project has long since shipped (I hope) but others who search for this might find it helpful.

Comment: I'm still going to get back to this and check this out. In the meanwhile, I'm looking into jss. Do you have anything to share with jss? Thanks! @t-to-the-j

Comment: Haven't tried it. Just to clarify on my answer above, I'm not actually preventing duplicate imports, Im allowing them to happen then using purgeCSS/optimize-css to treeshake/minimize.  Works out the same though.

https://gist.github.com/tmartin2089/9c83fbead9347c22e2eed583e0ff9884

Here's a gist of what finally worked for me.

Comment: This issue was causing child styles to be overwritten by their parent's styles in my project. Was able to resolve this by ensuring the styles are imported last in a component. This ensures the child's styles are added after styles added by other imports including the duplicates mentioned above. Happy to help if anyone needs more details.